# Why can't my materials show color? I need to add a texture?

Tags: texturing, materials, color

I've followed a lot of tutorials. Every time, in the tutorial they add a material and change the base color and the object changes color. But when I do that I get a pink -Texture Missing- type of color. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Could you please check your material override? Under view layer (one with a lot of photos), and under "Override".

Comment: Thanks, but there was nothing in the material override. I think something weird is happening with the Principled BSDF shader. I think it's trying to automatically assign the right shader and it's just getting it wrong. sometimes just clicking on the color or unassigning the material and reassigning it causes it to temporary turn white like I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I figured it out... if I change the surface from "Principled BSDF" to "Diffuse BSDF" then I can select the color I want. From what I understand, "Principled BSDF" is a shader that combines elements of many shaders. I guess, somewhere, something is going wrong on my computer. Therefore selecting a simpler shader works better. I am using an Intel i5 mobile processor with built in graphics.